# React native change state loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a react native app where a `post` has `comments`. I only want to
show the `comments` when the user clicks on `load comments...`. The problem 
is how do I handle the state for each post (there are multiple posts). I tried
this but it's not working (renderPost is a loop):

```
const renderPost = ({ item, index}) => {
    let fetchComments = false;

    return (
      <View style={[t.mB6]}>
        <View style={[t.roundedLg, t.overflowHidden, t.shadow, t.bgWhite, t.hAuto]}>

        <TouchableOpacity 
            key={item.id}
            onPress={() => {
              fetchComments = true;
            }}>
            <Text style={[t.fontBold, t.textBlack, t.mT2, t.mL4, t.w1_2]}>
                load comments...
              </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        { fetchComments ? <Comments postId={item.id}/> : null }
      </View>
    )
  }
```

In the code above I set `let fetchComments` to true when the user clicks on `load comments...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

renderPost is a functional component that doesn't have its own render and its own state, you may resolve this passing a function that changes state through renderPost props in its Father React.Component.

Example:

```
//imports

class FatherComponentWithState extends React.component{
  state={
    fetchComments:false,
    //(...OTHERSTUFFS)
    }

  setFetchComments = () =>{
    this.setState({fetchComments:true})
  }

  render(){
    return(
//(...FatherComponentStuffs)
      {new renderPost({
         setFetchComments: this.setFetchComments, 
         fetchComments:this.state.fetchComments,
         //(...renderPostOtherStuffs like item, index)
      })}
  //(...FatherComponentStuffs)
)}}
```

The renderPost function will receive it with something like this:

```
const renderPost = (props) =>{

let fetchComments = props.fetchComments;
let setFetchComments = props.setFetchComments;
let item = props.item
let index = props.index

//...renderPost return remains the same
}
```

P.S.: If you have multiple renderPosts, you can use fetchComments as an array of booleans and set the state to true passing an index as parameter of the setFetchComments function.